# Monotouch - Write to the console from an iPad

Tags: console, xamarin.ios

In monotouch, how can I write to the console which the iPhone Configuration Utility displays.

This is the console I am referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

and with Monotouch's magic, this gets output to the console.